# SSIS Import Multiple Files and Create Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm using SSIS and am importing multiple (30) txt files.  I create the table on the fly using the file name of the txt file and creating the columns based on the first row from the txt file - all this works.  My code stops working when an apostrophe ' is in one of the fields.

The files are delimitated using a |

My code:

```
SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


        string line1 = "";
        //Reading file names one by one
        string SourceDirectory = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
          string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            // do something with fileName
            string columname = "";

            //Reading first line of each file and assign to variable
            System.IO.StreamReader file2 =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);

            string filenameonly = ((((fileName.Replace(SourceDirectory, "")).Replace(".txt", "")).Replace("\\", "")).Replace("-", "_"));
            line1 = (" IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]." + filenameonly + "') AND type in (N'U'))DROP TABLE [dbo]." + filenameonly + " Create Table dbo." + filenameonly + "([" + file2.ReadLine().Replace("|", "] NVARCHAR(500),[") + "] NVARCHAR(500))").Replace(".txt", "");

            file2.Close();

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(line1, myADONETConnection);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();      

            MessageBox.Show("TABLE IS CREATED");

            //Writing Data of File Into Table
            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
            while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    columname = line.ToString();
                    columname = "[" + columname.Replace("|", "],[") + "]";
                }

                else
                {
                    string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace("|", "','") + "')";
                    SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                    myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                counter++;
            }

            SourceFile.Close();
```

The offending line is:

```
string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace("|", "','") + "')";
```

I tried amending to the below to replace the apostrophe to no avail:

```
string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace("|", "','") + line.Replace("'''", "") + "')";

string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace("'", "") + "')";
```

Also nesting the replace does not work:

```
string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace(line.Replace("'''", ""),"|" ) + "')";
```

The below does not import anything:

```
string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace("|", "','").Replace("'", "") + "')";
```

Changing to the below imports all but then fails over at the line with the apostrophe:

```
string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace("|", "','").Replace("'''", "") + "')";
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating the two REPLACE() functions like your first attempt, you should nest them.

```
Replace(
  Replace({arguments to remove apostrophe character}), 
  {arguments to remove pipe character}
)
```

If you want to keep the C# usage of `string.Replace()`, you would nest like this:

```
line.Replace({arguments to replace apostrophe).Replace({arguments to replace pipe})
```

Or you could do it in two separate statements:

```
line = line.Replace({arguments to replace apostrophe});
line = line.Replace({arguments to replace pipe});
```

Comment: I still cannot get it to work as per recent edit.  I won't be able to do it on two separate statements as needed as part of the SQL Insert

Comment: You can do it on two separate statements if do it prior to using it to create the insert.   I don't see any reason you can't do it that way.   Use a local variable if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: I show you in my most recent edit.   Since `line` is already a local variable you can just use that.   Look at my last code snippet.   Do those two lines of code BEFORE you build the Insert statement.